# Unable to rotate a view

Tags: objective-c, rotation, xcode4.2, storyboard

I am using Xcode 4.2 to develop a storyboard application.

I am trying to rotate views but it is not working. I made sure that the app supports the 4 rotations in the summary as well as in the "info" section.

I have two types of supported orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //check if device is iPad
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

I tried it on the iPhone simulator and it is not working, but for the iPad it works perfectly fine... any reasons?

I am using a Tab Bar view controller if this makes any difference ...

Comment: what do you expect? auto rotate for both iPad and iPhone? the first method saying auto rotate is enable only for iPad

Comment: I expect to rotate all the view in ipad and some views in iphone . in some views I use the first method and in the others I use the second one.
on ipad all the views rotate perfectly , but the ones I selected to rotate on iPhone (with the second method) do not rotate

Comment: what do you mean "not working"? does it rotate for all views or not rotate at all? also where do you put this method? should be in UIViewController not UIView

Comment: not working means that the views that are supposed to rotate are not rotating at all 
all my classes inherit from UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html) document

> All child view controllers in your UITabBarController or
>   UINavigationController do not agree on a common orientation set. To
>   make sure that all your child view controllers rotate correctly, you
>   must implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for each view
>   controller representing each tab or navigation level. Each must agree
>   on the same orientation for that rotate to occur. That is, they all
>   should return YES for the same orientation positions.

so make sure all view controller in your tab bar controller return `YES` for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

Comment: `Each must agree on the same orientation for that rotate to occur. That is, they all should return YES for the same orientation positions` didn't know that. thanks